# selecting bootstrap dropdown value by key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap btn-group dropdown menu as my combo box for dropdown.
Working fine.

```
<div class="btn-group insertText insertTextSMSTemplate">
    <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a Value</button>
    <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style='padding:2px;'><span class="icon-chevron-down"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 100px; overflow: auto">
        <li><a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <!-- <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I wrote a jquery function to select the selected li value and make button text.

But problem is that My list is long and I have scroll in the dropdown.So If I want to select say 70th li element from the dropdown I have to scroll down and select.

I want to add a feature to it that if 70th value is "Temp" then If I press "T" the words starting from T from the list only show in the dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

I needed this too. Here is my working solution for Bootstrap 3 focus / select by key input with jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown").bind('keydown', function(event) {
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var selectedItem = $(this).find('a').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().indexOf(keyChar) === 0; }).first();
    selectedItem.focus();
});
```

Explanation: The idea is to get all the focusable elements in the list, in this case the  tags, then filter them by some method to test if your pressed key is the first character.

Hope this helps

Comment: This simple solution is good for something with caps like acronyms, alpha-codes etc. As @Edwin_Vincent points out, you can add ```.ToLowerCase()``` if your tags are downcased. His solution above is good too for repeat key press.

Answer (score 4):

modified verison of jenkilabs' code.
if you wanted to loop thru the items that begin with the key press then use this:

```
        $(".dropdown").bind('keydown', function (event) {
            //this will open the list if it is not open and select a value 
            if (event.keyCode != 13){ 
                    if ($(this).find('button').attr('aria-expanded') == 'false')
                    {
                        $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
                    }
            }
            var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
            var selectedItems = $(this).find('a').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyChar) === 0;
            });
            var f = $(selectedItems).is(':focus');
            if (f)
            {
                selectedItems = $('a:focus').parent().nextAll().find('a').filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyChar) === 0;
                }).first();
                if (selectedItems.length == 0)
                {
                    selectedItems = $(this).find('a').filter(function () {
                        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyChar) === 0;
                    });
                }
            }
            selectedItems.first().focus();
        });
```

the .ToLowerCase will allow you to select items that begin with lowercase 
characters, and you don't have to group items that begin with the same 
character together ex.

1. a
2. a
3. b
4. a

this code will find the third 'a' at no. 4, if you kept pressing a, then it will go back up to the first 'a'.

this will work as long as this(see below) is the structure of the dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a>text here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

make sure `<a>` is nested within the `<li></li>` and that there is a div with class="dropdown" surrounding the `<button>` and `<ul>`

Comment: Nice. This is probably better for completeness than my use case required.

Comment: @genkilabs Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below should work. Not sure though not tried running.

```
$("#ID").keydown(function(e){ // the keydown even on ul
    var chr =String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    $(this).find("li").each(function(){ // if the key down is not in UL then make sure the "this" should refer to UL
      var name = $(this).text();
        if( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(chr.toLowerCase()) === 0 ) {
            $(this).focus(); // this should focus you
            return false; 
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in using a plugin, you could use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). It's pretty easy to use and when you initialise select as a select2 element, it will include a searchbar that will automatically filter the options as you type in it.

Here are [the examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) so you can see if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, I solved it like this:

first add ids to ul and button
then do the following

```
$('#buttonId').on('keyup', function(){ 
       var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
       if(event.which !== 8) {
           keyChar += key;
       } 
       if(event.which === 8) {
          keyChar = keyChar.slice(0, -1);
       }
       var regex = new RegExp('^' + keyChar, 'i');

       $("#ulId li").each(function(){
         if(regex.test($(this).text())) {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
            $(this).addClass('active');
         }else{
            $(this).css("display", "none");
         }
       });
 });
 $('#ulId').on('blur', function(){ 
   keyChar = '';
   });
```

NB. also globally define keyChar as null

Answer (score 0):

As I ended up here myself 9 years after the original question I figured id provide an updated answer. [genkilabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484689/genkilabs) answer is still perfectly serviceable but I wanted to use vanilla js as everything possible with jQuery is now easily achievable in vanilla JavaScript.

I have only tested this for Bootstrap 4 but as its based on genkilabs answer for Bootstrap 3 it should also work there.

```
/**
 * This is a workaround for the fact that Bootstrap 4 dropdowns don't support keyboard navigation.
 */
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(function (dropdown) {
  dropdown.addEventListener('keydown', dropdownKeydownHandler);
});

/**
 * Focuses an <a> element within the dropdown based on matching the key press to the first letter of the link text.
 * @param event - keydown event
 */
function dropdownKeydownHandler(event) {
  const pressedKey = event.key.toUpperCase(); //Assume all our dropdowns are uppercase
  const dropdownDescendants = this.querySelectorAll('a'); //Get all the link elements within the dropdown
  const firstDescendentMatchingKeyPress = Array.from(dropdownDescendants).find((element) => { //turn the NodeList into an array so we can use find()
    return element.innerText.toUpperCase().startsWith(pressedKey); //Find the first link which has inner text starting with the pressed key
  });

  firstDescendentMatchingKeyPress.focus(); //Focus the link
}
```

If you run into the issue of the original dropdown-toggle control element being focused by this code then you can exclude it by adding this to the find()

```
if (element.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle')) //if the link is the dropdown toggle itself, skip it
{
  return false;
}
```